# Grouping data in SQL Server for particular patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't been able to find an SQL Server question that is like this scenario. I have data in the following format.

```
Recnum    SectionID    CategoryID    EnterTime     LeaveTime
534       2            4             <time here>   <time here>   
535       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  
532       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  
523       2            4             <time here>   <time here>  
512       2            4             <time here>   <time here>  
577       2            NULL          <time here>   <time here>  
578       1            6             <time here>   <time here>  
579       2            2             <time here>   <time here>   
571       2            2             <time here>   <time here>    
588       2            2             <time here>   <time here>
```

I need to add a GroupID column so the data looks like the following.

```
Recnum    SectionID    CategoryID    EnterTime     LeaveTime    GroupID
534       2            4             <time here>   <time here>  NULL 
535       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  1
532       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  1
523       2            4             <time here>   <time here>  NULL
512       2            4             <time here>   <time here>  NULL
577       2            NULL          <time here>   <time here>  2
578       1            6             <time here>   <time here>  NULL
579       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  3  
571       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  3
588       2            2             <time here>   <time here>  3
```

The GroupID is used for cases where the SectionID and CategoryID are both 2 or SectionID is 2 and CategoryID is NULL. The GroupID must be the same when there are several of these patterns in a row ordered by EnterTime and must increment for the next set of the group. The Recnum is the PK but it's not in order by the EnterTime. I can do this in a WHILE loop but the table is over 35 million records so that could day days to process. Any idea on how to do this?

```
Example of the times for two rows:
Enter                     Leave
2011-05-31 21:04:07.000   2011-05-31 21:04:35.000
2011-05-31 21:04:35.000   2011-05-31 21:04:44.000
```

Comment: _The GroupID must be the same when there are several of these patterns in a row ordered by EnterTime_ what is the timeframe used? - 5 minutes, 10 minutes?  Can you post some of the times from the table?

Comment: The times are usually between 1 to 30 seconds but could be hours on some occasions. This data has been collected over the past 4 years and there have been bugs that caused the EnterTime and LeaveTime to have gaps between the rows. I added an example to the question.

Comment: Obviously, the "simplest" way to do this is with an iterative loop, but I appreciate your speed concerns. However, any set-based solution is going to require such massive temporary tables that I fear you're in danger of blowing tempdb. How about an ultra-tuned loop to select the Recnum and required GroupID to a result set, which you use subsequently to update your table with 1 statement. Might be possible to do this fast enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are not constrained to do this within sql server, your best bet is to

1. export your data to a text file
2. write a program in your favorite language to process that text file (i would recommend just exporting recnum and the new groupid, and only those where the groupid is not null)

   - even over 35 million+ rows, this should only take a few minutes
3. use a [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to bring your data back into sql server

   - again, just a few minutes
4. use an UPDATE ... FROM statement to join your bulk-inserted table back to your 
   original table to update the groupid column

   ```
   UPDATE o 
   SET GroupID = bi.GroupID
   FROM OriginalTable o 
       INNER JOIN BulkInsertTable bi 
       ON o.RecNum = bi.RecNum
   ```

   - this one will take significantly longer, but since the time it is taking is the time to write your data to disk, it is unavoidable

Comment: Excellent idea! I tried a CTE solution but the query became too complicated. The bulk export, process, and import completed in less than 5 minutes. Yes, I only exported the Recnum and GroupID from the app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create SQL Function which returns GroupId in your scenario
Then Update Table with this function

```
UPDATE TABLE SET GroupId=DBO.YOURFUNCTION(SectionID,CategoryID)
```

Your Function Sample is here

`CREATE FUNCTION GROUPIDFINDER (
@SectionID INT,
@CategoryID INT
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int`

```
IF @SectionID=2 AND @CategoryID=2
BEGIN
SET @Result=1
END
-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Result
```

END
GO