# Efficient insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm looking for an efficient way of inserting records into SQL server for my C#/MVC application. Anyone know what the best method would be?

Normally I've just done a while loop and insert statement within, but then again I've not had quite so many records to deal with.  I need to insert around half a million, and at 300 rows a minute with the while loop, I'll be here all day!

What I'm doing is looping through a large holding table, and using it's rows to create records in a different table. I've set up some functions for lookup data which is necessary for the new table, and this is no doubt adding to the drain.

So here is the query I have.  Extremely inefficient for large amounts of data!

```
Declare @HoldingID int
Set @HoldingID = (Select min(HoldingID) From HoldingTable)

While @JourneyHoldingID IS NOT NULL
Begin
    Insert Into Journeys (DepartureID, ArrivalID, ProviderID, JourneyNumber, Active)
    Select 
        dbo.GetHubIDFromName(StartHubName), 
        dbo.GetHubIDFromName(EndHubName), 
        dbo.GetBusIDFromName(CompanyName), 
        JourneyNo, 1
    From Holding
    Where HoldingID = @HoldingID

    Set @HoldingID = (Select MIN(HoldingID) From Holding Where HoldingID > @HoldingID)
End
```

I've heard about set-based approaches - is there anything that might work for the above problem?

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729250/grouping-data-in-sql-server-for-particular-patterns/12730333#12730333)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be exactly what you are doing now.

```
Insert Into Journeys(DepartureID, ArrivalID, ProviderID, JourneyNumber, Active)
Select 
    dbo.GetHubIDFromName(StartHubName), 
    dbo.GetHubIDFromName(EndHubName), 
    dbo.GetBusIDFromName(CompanyName), 
    JourneyNo, 1
From Holding
ORDER BY HoldingID ASC
```

Comment: Talk about making things complicated for myself. Such an easy solution - half a million rows inserted in less than 5 minutes.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 5):

If you want to insert a lot of data into a MSSQL Server then you should use [BULK INSERTs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) - there is a command line tool called the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) for this, and also a C# wrapper for performing [Bulk Copy Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a.aspx), but under the covers they are all using `BULK INSERT`.

Depending on your application you may want to insert your data into a staging table first, and then either [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) or `INSERT INTO SELECT...` to transfer those rows from the staging table(s) to the target table(s) - if you have a lot of data then this will take some time, however will be a *lot* quicker than performing the inserts individually.

If you want to speed this up then are [various things that you can do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) such as changing the recovery model or tweaking / removing triggers and indexes (depending on whether or not this is a live database or not).  If its still really slow then you should look into doing this process in batches (e.g. 1000 rows at a time).

Comment: Yeah I used bulk inserts to get the data into the holding table in the first place. Can you actually use that if you need to do some work on each row though i.e. use lookup functions to get the correct IDs?

Comment: @e-on Does the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement help?  I have to admit I've never used it before - only came across it researching it for this question.  I would make sure that the information in the staging table is up to date before performing the merge in order to minimise the number of function calls that you do.

Comment: It looks like it could be useful - will need to do a bit of reading up on it.

Answer (score 1):

you (probably) are able to do it in one statement of the form

```
INSERT INTO JOURNEYS
SELECT * FROM HOLDING;
```

Without more information about your schema it is difficult to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer 2008 introduced Table Parameters. These allow you to insert multiple rows in a single trip to the database (send it as a large blob). Without using a temporary table. This article describes how it works (step four in the article)

http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/05/16/sql-server-high-performance-inserts/

It differs from bulk inserts in that you do not need special utilities and that all constraints and foreign keys are checked.

I quadrupled my throughput using this and parallelizing the inserts. Now at 15.000 inserts/second in the same table sustained. Regular table with indexes and over a billion rows.